# Dynamically Add a Lookup to a CRM 2013 Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to programmatically add a lookup field to a form using JavaScript?

I can't seem to find anything in the SDK, so I assume it is not supported. Has anyone accomplished this using unsupported methods?

Comment: also if you can add dynamically a lookup, where you will store the value if there isn't a field in the database?

Comment: If this is already a field, why not add it the form and then hide or reveal it using script or Business Rules?

Comment: The field does already exist. I was implementing a bulk entry. I wanted to duplicate the field when a button was clicked and give it a different id, store those values then loop through them on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to my knowledge, this is not something that can be achieved, wanted to do something similar myself but had to scrap the idea

Comment: Yeah seems unachievable. I instead retrieved all the records I wanted and added a text field with jQueryUI autocomplete. Not quite as nice, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @enifeder same here! and if multiple lookups are involved there is a way to filter the results of lookups to get a desired outcome